# Chisel2 code run invoking compatibility layer - type casting issues

Tags: riscv, chisel

Interested in getting some of the `Chisel2` code to work within the `Chisel3` equilibrium, I managed to have `Chisel2` chisel-tutorial examples like `FullAdder`:

```
class FullAdder extends Module { 
  val io = new Bundle { 
    val a    = UInt(INPUT, 1) 
    val b    = UInt(INPUT, 1) 
    val cin  = UInt(INPUT, 1) 
    val sum  = UInt(OUTPUT, 1) 
    val cout = UInt(OUTPUT, 1) 
  } 
  // Generate the sum 
  val a_xor_b = io.a ^ io.b 
  io.sum := a_xor_b ^ io.cin 
  // Generate the carry 
  val a_and_b = io.a & io.b 
  val b_and_cin = io.b & io.cin 
  val a_and_cin = io.a & io.cin 
  io.cout := a_and_b | b_and_cin | a_and_cin 
}
```

up and running with the command:

```
>test:runMain examples.Launcher FullAdder
```

using a bit of magic dust contained in the line:

```
import Chisel._
```

However, once I tried instantiating that `FullAdder` in this example (adding, of course, `import Chisel._`):

```
class Adder(val n:Int) extends Module {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val A    = UInt(INPUT, n)
    val B    = UInt(INPUT, n)
    val Cin  = UInt(INPUT, 1)
    val Sum  = UInt(OUTPUT, n)
    val Cout = UInt(OUTPUT, 1)
  }
  //create a vector of FullAdders
  val FAs   = Vec(n, Module(new FullAdder()).io)
  val carry = Wire(Vec(n+1, UInt(width = 1)))
  val sum   = Wire(Vec(n, Bool()))

  //first carry is the top level carry in
  carry(0) := io.Cin

  //wire up the ports of the full adders
  for (i <- 0 until n) {
    FAs(i).a := io.A(i)
    FAs(i).b := io.B(i)
    FAs(i).cin := carry(i)
    carry(i+1) := FAs(i).cout
    sum(i) := FAs(i).sum.toBool()
  }
  io.Sum := sum.toBits.toUInt()
  io.Cout := carry(n)
}
```

I got an error concerning this line:

```
  io.Sum := sum.toBits.toUInt()
```

as follows:

```
[error] /home/apaj/testing-learning-journey/learning-journey/src/main/scala/examples/Adder.scala:32: not enough arguments for method toUInt: (implicit compileOptions: chisel3.core.CompileOptions)chisel3.core.UInt.
[error] Unspecified value parameter compileOptions.
[error]   io.Sum := sum.toBits.toUInt()
```

Information found [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Chisel3-vs-Chisel2) and [here](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial/wiki/Basic-Types-and-Operations#casting-between-types) enabled me to conclude that I should try with `asUInt()` instead of `toUInt()`.

However, that leads to the following output to my reqest:

```
> test:run-main examples.Launcher Adder
[info] Running examples.Launcher Adder
Starting tutorial Adder
[info] [0.001] Elaborating design...
chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException: bits to be indexed 'chisel3.core.UInt@30' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type
```

which is followed by a lot of java-like complaints and concludes with:

```
================================================================================
Errors: 1: in the following tutorials
Tutorial Adder: exception bits to be indexed 'chisel3.core.UInt@30' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type
================================================================================
```

The only relevant resource I could find is this [bug report](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/202), but I am really at a loss how to implement this advice and where exactly should I attack this problem of *'chisel3.core.UInt@30' must be hardware*.

I guess I am missing something else I should import to enable the correct translation of `asUInt()` in this context, but I am afraid I am not seeing it. Kindly provide help if possible or at least directions for further reading - either is highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on the Chisel2 parts, but I think the problem (after your correct fix to use `io.Sum := sum.asUInt()`) is the line

```
  val FAs   = Vec(n, Module(new FullAdder()).io)
```

This is not instantiating a `Vec` of `FullAdders` but merely creating a Vec with elements of that type.  The following compiles for me. It creates the Vec from an Seq of instantiated FullAdders.

```
  val FAs   = VecInit(Seq.fill(n)(Module(new FullAdder()).io))
```

It is trying to disambiguate code like this that pushed the somewhat different API of chisel3.  I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, again. However, that line does not work for me. I get the response: `Adder.scala:17: not found: value VecInit` and it points to the line where VecInit is written. What does compile is: `val FAs   = Vec(Seq.fill(n)(Module(new FullAdder()).io))`, so without `Init`, but it still outputs warnings: `Adder.scala:33: method toBits in class Data is deprecated: Best alternative, .asUInt() [warn]   io.Sum := sum.toBits.asUInt()` and it points to the `toBits` position in text.

Comment: Could you please comment on where did I loose `Init` and why should I use `asUInt` as a replacement of `toBits`?

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow.  I think it might be because I am using the master branches of chisel and firrtl, I'll check it soon and let you know.  As to the asUInt, I was mostly just following the directive of the deprecation and seeing what worked.  I'll try and come up with a more specific answer too

Comment: Because you are using Chisel._ you need to explicitly add the

Comment: Because you are using Chisel._ you need to explicitly add the `import chisel3.core.VecInit`.  That should make the VecInit work for you.  In chisel3, even in chisel2 compatibility mode, the to* methods are deprecated in favor of as* methods. toBits is unnecessary since you asUInt applies to the Vec.